# Associating two fields with the same ID

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The website I'm writing uses the ID of one date field to return some data associated with it from an API. I need to implement a new date field, giving the user two input options. How can I associate the date submitted on the new field I'm creating with the ID of the old field that is used to return the data?

```html
<input class="dateinput" type="text" id="startDate" name="startDate">
```

Is later used by

```js
var input_startDate = document.getElementById("startDate");
```

to return data. I need to add another input field just like the first one as an option for the user.

Merely changing `getElementById` to `getElementsByClassName` wasn't enough for it to work.

It would actually be better if I could somehow "copy" the value from one field to the other, thus registering the value from the new field into the old one and then keeping getting the element ID.

Comment: Two fields cannot have the same id. You could use a `data-` attribute on one of the fields to link it to the other.

Comment: You'll need to change the javascript to use a class selector instead of an ID

Comment: share some code reference?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with `data-` attribute, will take a look. As for what return_false said. Shouldn't using a class selector mess things up? Or does it only take in consideration the element with some value associated? Because using a class selector will make so that half the elements within that class are empty.

Comment: It's hard for any of us to help with such a vague question.

Comment: You're going to have to change how the JavaScript selects the element to send to the API. It can't be just by ID, it needs to depend on the option the user chose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **getElementsByClassName** in the below way to work.

```js
var input_startDate_1 = document.getElementsByClassName("startDate")[0].value;
var input_startDate_2 = document.getElementsByClassName("startDate")[1].value;
console.log (input_startDate_1);
console.log (input_startDate_2);
```

```html
<input class="dateinput startDate" type="text" value="01-01-2021" name="startDate_1" />
<input class="dateinput startDate" type="text" value="02-01-2021" name="startDate_2" />
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it true that the non-null element of the class will automatically be at position `[0]`?

Comment: it will be based on sequence how you add your elements with respect to classes.